# Automatically sending mails from office

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, windows-registry, vba

I have VBA code in Excell that send mails, but every time it wait few second for me to  accept the sending.
Some time before I changed two (2) keys in registry and it sends without asking me for accepting, but I migrated computer and forgot where the keys are. Over internet there is very much bed solutions like to install some plugins and so on...
So shortly, my question is: what I need to change in registry for not to get little outlook's window with progress bar that demand me to accept the message sanding?

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Ron deBruin has [this page](http://www.rondebruin.nl/cdo.htm) on his site that describes how to send using CBO which should get rid of the message.

And this page (http://www.rondebruin.nl/sendmail.htm) has all his emailing with vba pages.

--EDIT-- in response to comment

Your currently "working" code is sending the email in a manner that makes the message appear. Using the code from the link I provided bypasses the mail system that requires the security message.

Quote from the link I provided above (emphasis added):

> What is CDO doing
>
> The example code is using CDOSYS (CDO
>   for Windows 2000). **It does not depend
>   on MAPI or CDO and hence is dialog
>   free and does not use your mail
>   program to send email.**
>
> Briefly to explain, this code builds
>   the message and drops it in the pickup
>   directory, and SMTP service running on
>   the machine picks it up and send it
>   out to the internet.

Another quote from the link you provide in the comments (again, emphasis added):

> Use CDO
>
> Tip (my favorite way to send mail)
>
> A much better option is to check out
>   this page and see if CDO is working on
>   your machine. Working with every mail
>   program (It will not use a mail
>   program) **There are no security
>   warnings when you use CDO to send
>   mail.** http://www.rondebruin.nl/cdo.htm

You'll need to change your code if you want to send without the messages.

Comment: Thank you for replay, but you don't understood my question, I have working code, all I need is to make to Outlook do not display him "accept window". Articles you give me have no answer. This page: http://www.rondebruin.nl/mail/prevent.htm refer to bad workarounds. I only need two registry key, and like I see any one do not know about them...

Answer (score 0):

[Advanced Security for Outlook](http://www.mapilab.com/outlook/security/?dstr) will fix this problem. It's freeware and works beautifully although I would never have bothered with it had I known about the code guitarthrower referenced.

I'd love to know those two registry keys too....